# Using selectedBackgroundView to show the highlighted state

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Imagine the scenario where you have a `UICollectionView` and in each cell you want to have a button fill the entire cell so that you can respond to various touch events to handle the highlight appearance. For example, when the user touches down on the button you want to change the background color of the button then revert it when they drag out or cancel the touch etc. Now imagine the case where instead of changing the button's background color you want to change the cell's `backgroundView`. A `UIButton` doesn't have a background view, just a `backgroundColor` or `backgroundImage`.

I have a solution but I wonder if it can be cleaner, if this approach is not recommended. Upon touching the button I loop over its `superview`s until I get the `UICollectionViewCell` then I set its `selected` property to `true`. In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I set up the `selectedBackgroundView` as desired. This obtains the desired behavior, but is it inappropriate to use the selected state to indicate the highlight state and manage it in this manner? What would be better?

I could get the `UICollectionViewCell` upon touching a button then change its `backgroundView` property instead of doing it when creating each cell, then there would be no need to change the `selected` value. But that still doesn't feel like a great solution.

Comment: How different would it be to use a regular UICollectionViewCell with a UILabel in it instead of a UIButton, then simply change the cell's contentView's backgroundColor? Your button doesn't seem to be doing anything special, and notice that a button inside a collection or table view cell *delays* its touch down animation/highlight because the cell itself gets checked for the selection event first.

Comment: @Matt Indeed the button isn't special, the only reason it's there is because a `UICollectionViewCell` is not a `UIControl` therefore you cannot detect TouchDown, TouchDragEnter, TouchCancel, etc, so there's no way to change the appearance when it's touched. You could when it's tapped (`didSelectItemAtIndexPath`) but not touched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a button inside the collection view cell just to set its highlight color when it is being pressed down. Simply set your cell's `selectedBackgroundView` to a view that has the same width and height as your cell, and give that view the `backgroundColor` you would like to highlight the cell with.

A (dirty) implementation I did is this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = {
        let bgview = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height))
        bgview.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return bgview
    }()
    return cell
}
```

And then, simply deselect the cell in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. The "holding downpress" will be automatically handled for you, and the deselection animation will only be triggered when the user lifts her finger.

I think this is dirty because you are setting the `selectedBackgroundView` everytime that the cell is being dequeued for reuse in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. What I would do is create a `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, set its `selectedBackgroundView` from in there, and register that cell using a `registerNib:` or `registerClass:` on the collection view.

---

Add: The cleaner version. In your custom collection view cell subclass, assign the `backgroundView` and the `selectedBackgroundView`:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
        return view
    }()

    self.selectedBackgroundView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return view
        }()
}
```

And the relevant methods in your view controlle, collection view data source, and delegate:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.registerClass(NSClassFromString("test.CustomCollectionViewCell"), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CELL")
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `selectedBackgroundView` is only displayed when you programmatically set `selected = true`, no? So that wouldn't cause that view to appear when you touch the cell.

Comment: Ah, but when you touch down on the collection view cell, selected becomes true--no need to set it in code. :) I'll edit my answer to provide a cleaner version...

Comment: This works well and is probably an even better solution than the one I found!

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice clean solution. `UICollectionViewCell`s already have a highlighted state that is automatically tracked for the various touch events that occur. However there is no `highlightedBackgroundView` like there is a `selectedBackgroundView`, but you can still utilize the highlighted state to modify the cell appearance upon highlight and unhighlight. Therefore there is no need to use a `UIButton` in each cell - a `UILabel` will do just fine.

Simply implement a couple of the `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods: `collectionView:didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:` and `collectionView:didUnhighlightItemAtIndexPath:`. Change the `backgroundView` property when it becomes highlighted, then set it back to `nil` when it becomes unhighlighted.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change `backgroundView` every time you hold down the cell--that property is supposed to be the background view when the cell *isn't* selected, i.e., its normal state.